# Return statement is missing even though code is properly formatted and the method is clearly called

Tags: java, debugging

I made sure to have all my braces in the right spot regarding the class but no luck. I get a return statement error while I am trying to print out the result of the calculations in my calculatePremium method. The errors I'm getting are at the bottom of my code.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    class Insurance 
    {
        public static void main (String args[]) 
        {
            int currentYear, birthYear;
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter current year >> ");
            currentYear = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter birth year >> ");
            birthYear = keyboard.nextInt();
            calculatePremium(currentYear, birthYear);
        }
    
        public static int calculatePremium(int currentYear, int birthYear) 
            {
    
            System.out.println("The premium is $" + ((currentYear - birthYear) /10 ) + (15) * 20 );
    
            }
    }

    

    Insurance.java:21: error: missing return statement
            }
            ^
    1 error
    sandbox $ java Insurance
    Error: Could not find or load main class Insurance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't want calculatePremium() to return anything, you should change the method header from this:

```
public static int calculatePremium(int currentYear, int birthYear)
```

To this:

```
public static void calculatePremium(int currentYear, int birthYear)
```

Right now you have the return type set to int. If you don't want a method to return a value, the return type needs to be void.

Answer (score 1):

There is presumably no class file because the source cannot be compiled because it is syntactically invalid - there is a missing return statement.

calulatePremium says it returns an int, so it needs to.

```
   public static int calculatePremium …
```

Fix the first bug first.

Answer (score 0):

The  problem is your method has a return type of `int` but you omitted the `return` statement. You can solve the problem by writing your method like the below code

```java
 public static int calculatePremium(int currentYear, int birthYear)
    {

      return (currentYear - birthYear) /10  + (15) * 20 ;

    }
```

And write your `main` method like this

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int currentYear, birthYear,premium;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter current year >> ");
        currentYear = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter current year >> ");
        birthYear = keyboard.nextInt();
        premium= calculatePremium(currentYear, birthYear);
        System.out.println("The premium is $" +premium);
    }
```

OR
change the return type to `void`

```java
 public static void calculatePremium(int currentYear, int birthYear)
    {

        System.out.println("The premium is $" + ((currentYear - birthYear) /10 ) + (15) * 20 );

    }
```